# Does using the unfold tactic followed by fold in Coq do anything?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Will `unfold def. fold def.` ever achieve anything in a Coq proof?

Put differently: will there ever be a difference between these two sequences of applications of tactics?:

- `unfold def. fold def. cbn.`
- `cbn.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the documentation for both `fold` (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.fold) and `unfold` (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.unfold) you can see that they do not expect the same kind of argument.
While `unfold` takes an identifier as argument, `fold` takes a term.

So if you have `def x y` in your goal, you can `unfold def` to access its definition, but then you might have to use `fold (def x y)` to return to the original goal.

In any case, there is no guarantee that `unfold def ; fold (def x y)` will result in nothing, since there might other occurrences of the unfolded `def x y` in the goal.

---

Here is a concrete example to see `fold` and `unfold` in action.
If the goal changes after a tactic, I put the new goal in a comment after the tactic. Note also the use of `Fail progress tac` which asserts that executing tactic `tac` will not affect the goal at all.

```
Definition foo (b : bool) :=
  if b then 0 else 1.

Goal foo true + 1 = foo false.
Proof.
  unfold foo.
  (* 0 + 1 = 1 *)
  Fail progress fold foo.
  fold (foo true).
  (* foo true + S (foo true) = S (foo true) *)
  Fail progress fold (foo false).
  unfold foo.
  (* 0 + 1 = 1 *)
  fold (foo false).
  (* 0 + foo false = foo false *)
  fold (foo true).
  (* foo true + foo false = foo false *)
  unfold foo at 2.
  (* foo true + 1 = foo false *)
```

As you can see, `fold foo` will not do anything, while `fold true` and `fold false` will, of course, it's also greedy, any `0` will turn into `fold true`.

Comment: Thank you! In cases where there is only one occurrence of the unfolded `def x y` in the goal then will the unfold/fold have no effect?

Comment: You said "you might have to use `fold (def x y)`". When would this be necessary?

Comment: I added a concrete example to my answer, hopefully this answers both your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. `unfold def` inlines the definition of `def`, and *also* performs some basic reductions e.g. if `def` was applied to anything before it got inlined.

```
Definition hold {T} (x : T) : Prop := True.
Goal (not False -> hold not).
unfold not.
(* inline not: (fun A : Prop => A -> False) False -> hold (fun A : Prop => A -> False)
   and reduce: (False -> False) -> hold (fun A : Prop => A -> False) *)
```

However, `fold def` does not "un-reduce" applications of `def`. If you now do

```
fold not.
```

it will *not* fold `False -> False` back to `not False`. It will only find the `not` under the `hold`, so you get `(False -> False) -> hold not` as your goal. (`fold (not False)` would reduce `not False` to `False -> False`, search for that, and then eventually give the goal `not False -> hold (fun A : Prop => A -> False`, but, again, it hasn't properly undone the `unfold`). So, basically, the sequence `unfold def. fold def.` inlines and simplifies usages of `def` where it has been "used" (e.g. applied), and tries to leave the other usages intact.

Another example, this time with iota-reduction (reducing a destruction) instead of beta-reduction.

```
Definition def : bool := true.
Definition truth (b : bool) : Prop := if b then True else False.
Goal ((if def then True else False) -> truth def).
unfold def.
(* inline def: (if true then True else False) -> truth true
   and reduce: True -> truth true *)
fold def.
(* goal: True -> truth def *)
```

In the first case, `cbn.` and `unfold not. fold not. cbn.` are different (and in neither case does `cbn` do anything). In this latter case, `cbn.` just takes us straight to `True -> True` no matter where we put it.